# C# XNA publishing problems when creating files

Tags: c#, file, xna, clickonce, publish

I've been publishing my game for me and my friend to test and I've started to make a text file in the code to use as an error log but I'm getting some problems and I can't find anything on the internet to help me.

I want it so the user can get the installation files, install it at a custom location, run it through a shortcut and so I can create files where the user installed it for saving the game, an error log and such.

What happens is, I make a clickonce application, but after using the setup.exe the shortcut isn't usable, it just says "program has stopped responding" because it's trying to make a file and I can't run it as administrator. I can only set administrator to the setup.exe, there's just no options for the game's shortcut or any of the clickonce applications. And I have no idea how to let the user choose an installation directory.

I've searched through google and the msdn library but I can't find anything. It says if I don't use clickonce deployment I need another installation package but I can't find anything. I also tried modifying the app.manifest to turn:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

to

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

but it won't allow me to publish it then because it's a clickonce application and if i turn it off in the security it just turns it back on when i try to publish it. Can someone please tell me my options, I just want a normal game installation like every other game it's driving me nuts I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question, but it might be what you actually need.

<s>You should be able to create and use files</s> in the ClickOnce applications deployment folder without any security restrictions (no admin rights needed), which you can access with

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

Note that when updating the application all the content in this folder will be rewritten, so you should recreate any log files and such you have.

### Edit

Actually, strike that - this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx) article says otherwise: you still need security permissions in order to read and write to this folder.

However, it also says that [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) is used exactly for this purpose: reading and writing application-specific data in partial trust, such as with un-elevated ClickOnce applications:

#### Isolated Storage

> Isolated Storage provides an API for creating and accessing files by
>   using a simple API. The actual location of the stored files is hidden
>   from both the developer and the user.
>
> Isolated Storage works in all versions of the .NET Framework. Isolated
>   Storage also works in partially trusted applications without the need
>   for additional permission grants. You should use Isolated Storage if
>   your application must run in partial trust, but must maintain
>   application-specific data.

### Edit 2

But still, before using isolated storage, try the application deployment directory - it works fine for me!